# json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 3 column 1 (char 4)

Tags: python, json, python-3.x

I have written a script which is hitting Azure DevOps API and get API response from it. The script is working file on local machine but when I am trying to run the same script from Azure pipeline it is giving me error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/azp/$AZP_AGENT_NAME/3/s/terra/agent/agent_queue_status.py", line 19, in <module>
    data = json.loads(r)
  File "/_work/_tool/Python/3.9.0/x64/lib/python3.9/json/__init__.py", line 346, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "/_work/_tool/Python/3.9.0/x64/lib/python3.9/json/decoder.py", line 337, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "/_work/_tool/Python/3.9.0/x64/lib/python3.9/json/decoder.py", line 355, in raw_decode
    raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 3 column 1 (char 4)
##[error]Bash exited with code '1'.
```

This the my script:

```
import base64
import requests
import json


AZURE_DEVOPS_PAT = 'my_pat'
authorization = str(base64.b64encode(bytes(':' + AZURE_DEVOPS_PAT, 'ascii')), 'ascii')
headers = {
    'Accept': 'application/json',
    'Authorization': 'Basic ' + authorization
}

url = 'https://dev.azure.com/{MY-ORG}/(MY-Project)/_settings/agentqueues?__rt=fps&__ver=2'
r = requests.get(url, headers=headers).text
data = json.loads(r)

print(data)
```

I tried everything. Like changing the way of getting response but no luck.

```
tried:-
r = requests.get(url, headers=headers).json
-------------------------------------------
r = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
data = r.json()
```

Please suggest something. The code is working fine on local machine but not with pipeline on Azure agent.

Comment: 1) `r = requests.get(url, headers=headers) print(r.status_code)` 2)print the `text` before `json.loads(r)`

Comment: Search for `JSONDecodeError`. In summary, what you're trying to decode is simply not JSON. Why? I can't tell without looking at it.

Comment: Can you provide sample of `response.text`

Comment: @balderman
In local machine, the status_code is "200" but in pipeline it is giving "203".
Also for response text, I entered `r.text' in code. In local machine it is giving me json response but in pipeline it is giving me HTML output.

Comment: and what is the `text` ?